# not able to set value to nil

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have the following code in `Objective-C`:

```
NSString *tempUserID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"userid"];
if (!tempUserId) {
    // Blah blah blah
}
```

I tried to rewrite in swift this way:

```
    var tempUserID: NSString = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("userid") as NSString
    if (tempUserID == nil) {

    }
```

But I get the following error:

`Type 'NSObject' does not conform to protocol NilLateralConvertiable`

Is there something i'm doing wrong? How can I check if the value is null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your variable as NSString? instead of NSString.

```
var tempUserID: NSString? = ...
```

Comment: I ended up doing this: `tempUserID: NSString? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("userid") as? NSString`. Notice the `?` after `as`

Comment: Why are you guys explicitly defining the type? It's Swift.

Comment: Can you tell us what you mean?